# Update article laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Controller article

```
 public function update(Request $request, Article $article){
    $article->update($request->except('slug', 'image_path'));
    if ($request->hasFile('image_path')) {
        $image = $request->file('image_path');
        $new_name = rand() . '.' . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $image->move(public_path('images'), $new_name);

        $article->image_path = $new_name;
        $article->save();
    }
    $article->categories()->detach();
    if ($request->has('categories')) {
        $article->categories()->attach($request->input('categories'));
    }
    $user=auth()->user();
    return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Raksts atjaunots!');

}

public function edit(Article $article){
    $user=auth()->user();
        return view('edit',[
            'article' => $article,
            'categories' => Category::with('children')->where('parent_id',0)->get(),
            'delimiter' => ''
        ]);
}
```

edit blade

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{route('update', $article)}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="display: flex;justify-content: center;flex-direction: column;">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">
    {{ csrf_field() }}

    {{-- Form include --}}

    <img src="{{URL::to('/images').'/'.$article->image_path}}" alt="">

    @include('partials.form')

    <input type="hidden" name="modified_by" value="{{Auth::id()}}">
  </form>
```

link to the form

```
<tbody>
    @foreach ($articles_suggest_user as $article)
        <a class="btn btn-default" href="{{route('edit', $article)}}"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
    <?php } ?>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/home/edit/{id}','Controller_Article_parents@edit', function () {
    return view('/home/edit');
 })->name('edit');


Route::get('/home/update/','Controller_Article_parents@update', function () {
  return view('/home');
 })->name('update');
```

When i clicked the link, i move to for example this url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/edit/190`

But my form is empty... input empty. How I can do when I open form it's display me input information ?

When click my link its display me form, but form is empty.

form example

```
<div class="rtq">
    <label for="parent_id">Cat</label>
    <span class="required">*</span>
    <select 
        id="parent_id" 
        class="form-control" 
        name="categories[]" 
        multiple="" 
        required
    >
        @include('admin.categories.partials.categories', 
            ['categories' => $categories,
             'current' => $article,
             'delimiter' => $delimiter])    
    </select>
</div>
<div class="rtq">
    <label for="">Descript</label>
    <textarea 
        name="description_short" 
        class="form-control" 
        id="description_short"
    >
        {{ $article->description_short ?? "" }}
    </textarea>
</div>
```

It my form . Mini example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to redirect with form input, you can use the `withInput()` function

```
return back()->withInput();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/redirects#creating-redirects

Now, this function is designed to be used with form validation and may not be what you want.

What I have done in the past when combining `create` & `edit` views into a single template is something like this:

```
{!! Form::text('name', isset($model) ? $model->name : null, [
        'class'         => 'form-control', 
        'placeholder'   => 'Please fill out this field &hellips;',
        'required'      => true
]) !!}
```

This uses the [Laravel Collective HTML library](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/6.0/html). However the principle is the same if you are using raw hmtl like so:

```
<input type="text" value="{{ isset($model) ? $model->name : null }}">
```

---

**Round 2** *Electric Boogaloo*

You aren't returning a variable called `$article` to your `edit.blade.php`.

---

**Round 3** *Apple Tree*

Originally, you appeared to be calling both a controller action **AND** also a callback function. Stick to the controller action only like so:

```
Route::get('/home/edit/{id}','Controller_Article_parents@edit')->name('edit');
```

Then within your `edit()` function on the Controller you will want to do this:

```
public function edit ($id) {
    return view('/home/edit', [
        'article' => Article::find($id)
    ]);
}
```

Comment: I when click this  ' '<a class="btn btn-default" href="{{route('edit', $article)}}"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a'' its display me to the form , but input i's empty. I want edit my input but its empty .

Comment: This sounds like a template issue, can you post the content of your form partial please? (i.e. the content of `@include('partials.form')`)

Comment: I add to the question mini form example. Cat dispaly. But input is empty

Comment: I just cleaned up your code and noticed you had a type here `{{ $article-.>description_short ?? "" }}`

Comment: it's just a typo. I have a phone case point. the fact is that var_dump($article) empty attribut return

Comment: See my updated answer, you aren't passing a variable called `$article` to your edit view!

Comment: i try this ... it's not work :( var_dump return me all fillable  but it's empty

Comment: Ok, i've done one last update to my answer which will hopefully sort out the problem. Trust me, the issue is a combination of the route and the view. If you still can't get the article variable to populate, make sure you haven't soft deleted the article you are trying to return

Comment: Huzzzaaahhhh!!! Good luck with the rest of your project mate!